# OpenGL Blending Color over Monochrome

Tags: opengl, blend

I am wanting to set up a blend (without using shaders preferably) to produce the following.

I have a black/white textured quad, and a quad of a solid color(for example red).  I'd like the blend to show the color (red) where all the white pixels are and black otherwise.

Is this possible and what does the code look like?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this using OpenGL, but using a bitwise AND on the two textures would lead to this result.

Comment: I want to say "use the stencil buffer" but unfortunately can't give any specifics as I haven't actually used stencils beyond OpenGL tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically not done by blending, but you could try `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ZERO);` drawing the red quad on top of the text.

However this will only work if there's no other content in the framebuffer.

Comment: Since the availability of FBOs and shaders: Render each layer into it's own texture, then combine the textures in the desired way (multitexturing with GL_MODULATE mode, or using an apropriate fragment shader). Technically you're implementing layers like found in Photoshop. Without the use of layers this kind of combination gets a little cumbersome.